# Is there a way to share state between all instances of a React component?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a reusable component that, inside a `useEffect`, loads some data from an API, stores it inside a state which is then used by it in some way.

However, in some pages, this same component is reused in multiple places, making multiple calls for the same data.

So, I would like to have a cache of sorts, where I store the retrieved values and reuse it in other instances if it wasn't fetched too long ago.

I don't really want to store it in a global state like Redux or (partially) Context because this is just a small detail of a reusable component.

The only solution I could come up with was using an external variable as the cache:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

let cache = null;
let cacheFetchedTime = null;

export const MyDropdown = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (cacheFetchedTime && Date.now() - cacheFetchedTime.getTime() < 5000) {
        setData(cache);
        return;
      }

      const fetchedData = await fetchData();
      setData(fetchedData);
      cache = fetchedData;
      cacheFetchedTime = new Date();
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* use `data` somehow */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is this the best (or only) way of doing this or is there a better alternative?

Comment: You can use local storage or context API. I think context API would be easy for you!

Comment: [Lifting up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#:~:text=In%20React%2C%20sharing%20state%20is,it%20into%20the%20Calculator%20instead.) is a central concept to react, allowing sharing of state between components in a top-down pattern. Worth reading about that and about [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Using context would force someone other than the component to know about this implementation detail, which is the reason some of these components were created.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use context or redux for this? I don't really understand your reasoning. I'd think if this data is getting used in multiple places in the app then it can't really be *that* small of an implementation detail...?

Comment: I don't want to use Redux or Context because this is an implementation detail of this specific component, and there is no real reason to force an ancestor of that component to hold the data for them. The **component** itself is being used everywhere, not the data alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to keep my cache at the top-level of the file where the component is at.

More specifically, I created an HOC that receives the getter function and returns a function that caches its answer for x period of time:

```
/* createCachedCall.js */

const createCachedCall = ({ callback, ms = 5000 }) => {
  let ongoingAsyncCall = null
  let result = null
  let lastFetchDate = null

  return async () => {
    if (ongoingAsyncCall) return ongoingAsyncCall

    if (lastFetchDate && Date.now() - lastFetchDate.getTime() <= ms)
      return result

    ongoingAsyncCall = Promise.resolve(callback())
    result = await ongoingAsyncCall
    lastFetchDate = new Date()
    ongoingAsyncCall = null

    return result
  }
}


/* MyDropdown.jsx */

const getDataCached = createCachedCall({
  callback: getData,
  ms: 300000, // 5 minutes
})

export const MyDropdown = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await getDataCached();
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* use `data` somehow */}
    </div>
  );
};
```